# MySQL Error: 1337

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error while trying to create a procedure in MySQL:

```
Error Code: 1337
Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration
```

even after doing a lot of Googling I found no relevant solution to my problem. My procedure is as below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE emp_dates(IN startDate DATE, IN endDate DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE fromDt DATETIME;
DECLARE toDt DATETIME;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE employees CURSOR FOR SELECT empid FROM employees;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;
DECLARE emp VARCHAR(20);
SET fromDt=startDate;
SET toDt=endDate;

OPEN employees;

WHILE fromDt<=toDt DO
REPEAT
    FETCH employees INTO emp;
    IF NOT done THEN
    INSERT INTO new_attendance_2(attid,empid,dt) VALUES(DEFAULT,emp,fromDt);
    END IF
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
SET fromDt=DATE_ADD(fromDt, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
LOOP
CLOSE employees;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

The purpose is to create a procedure which will take two dates as input and insert records in other table for every day that comes in between of those two.
Somebody please help! I appreciate any little help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's complaining about:

> `Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration`

So I would be looking at that location, where you do *indeed* declare variables after the cursor and handler:

```
   DECLARE employees CURSOR FOR SELECT empid FROM employees;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;
>> DECLARE emp VARCHAR(20);
```

If you modify your declarations thus, it should be okay:

```
DECLARE fromDt DATETIME;
DECLARE toDt DATETIME;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE emp VARCHAR(20);

DECLARE employees CURSOR FOR SELECT empid FROM employees;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;
```

The order has to be, as per [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html):

> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.

Comment: @paxdiablo, It's not obvious at all. Everyone would read it as "variable has an error, or condition declaration after cursor has an error, or handler declaration has an error".

Comment: @Pacerier, I didn't say the _wording_ was obvious, just that it was obviously complaining _with that phrase,_ so that's where you should look. Agree it _could_ be read as error with "(Variable) or (condition declaration after cursor) or (handler declaration)" but, in this case, it's actually "(Variable or condition declaration) after (cursor or handler declaration)", which is the way _I_ read it so obviously not _everyone_ would read it in the manner you describe. But that may just be because I'm weirder than most folk :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to re-order your declarations.

```
Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations 
and after variable and condition declarations.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html

Comment: I did it wrong because it is not logic. Why do cursors need to be declared **after** variable declarations is unknown for me.

Comment: @Lucio, "logical", not "logic".